# Calculating Fiscal Year

Tags: 2013, document-library, column, default-value

I am creating a document library in SharePoint 2013, where I want to have a column which shows the fiscal year (= not the date, only the year). It has to be a choice menu, since people in the beginning are going to upload old documents. However, I would like the *default value* to be a calculated value, which shows the fiscal year based on the value of the "Created" column. Our fiscal year runs from July to June.

Example: 
A report is created and uploaded 15th July 2014. Fiscal Year column shows "FY 2015".

So, could someone smarter than me help me with coming up with a nice calculation to solve my problem?

Btw, I am just a basic user of SharePoint, so I don't know how to use SharePoint Designer.

---

> What version of SharePoint do you have? How do you plan to enter the
>   data in your list, using a web part form? – cubanGuy

I am using SharePoint 2013. I'm trying to use a document library which I have added different required columns to so that the users can sort out the documents that affect them and their organization. This library is then used by different users with different views, and they independently upload their documents to the library and enter the data in the required columns.

What I'm asking here is how I automatically in a column can determine the default value of the current fiscal year as a calculated value, since I want the process to be as easy as possible for the users, since there already are so many other columns that they have to fill in.

---

> Please mark Anders' answer as your accepted solution instead of
>   editing your post –  Robert Lindgren

For some reason I can't mark the question and accept it? I don't see the check box. (And btw, I can't comment either as you asked me before since I'm a new user and have to have 50 reputation points for that. That's why I have to edit my posts.)

Comment: Glad it helped, should mark it as answer to "close" question :)

Comment: Please mark Anders' answer as your accepted solution instead of editing your post

Answer (score 6):

This will give you the format 2013-2014, 2014-2015:

```
=IF(MONTH(Created)>6,YEAR(Created)&"-"&YEAR(Created)+1,YEAR(Created)-1&"-"&YEAR(Created))
```

It takes MONTH>6, so you could adjust that parameter for fiscal start.

And for FY 2014, FY 2015 etc, you could use this formula:

```
=IF(MONTH(Created)>6,"FY "&YEAR(Created)+1,"FY "&YEAR(Created))
```

Answer (score 2):

This formula should work:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(Created),10,1)>Created,YEAR(Created),YEAR(Created)+1)
```

This is an adaptation from this [link](http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/09/sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/). Created is a column that stores what the name implies. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! But doesn't that formula imply (talking about the +1) that the fiscal year would be just pushed forward with one whole year? Our fiscal year changes in July, so the year should just be pushed forward with 6 months. That's actually my problem; I only want to show the *year*, while the fiscal year is 6 *months* ahead. And what's the 10,1 in the formula? Is that the date (1st Octoer) which is mentioned in the link you posted? How can I get that automatically filled in?

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you have? How do you plan to enter the data in your list, using a web part form?

Comment: @Erica, this is saying that, if Oct. 1 is after our Created date (we are prior to Oct. 1, 00:00 AM), then our Year is the same as the current year. If Oct. 1 is before our Created date (we are after Oct. 1, 00:00 AM), it will give us our current year plus one. This is normally what you want. But if the FY runs from July - June, you actually have to make it `=IF(DATE(YEAR(Created),7,1)>Created,YEAR(Created),YEAR(Created)+1)`, instead.