# Calculating Fiscal Year in YY format

Tags: calculated-column

I found this post and it worked for a 4-digit year but I am trying to use a 2-digit year

[Calculating Fiscal Year](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/110089/42907)

This will give you the format 2013-2014, 2014-2015:

```
=IF(MONTH(Created)>6,YEAR(Created)&"-"&YEAR(Created)+1,YEAR(Created)-1&"-"&YEAR(Created))
```

It takes `MONTH>6`, so you could adjust that parameter for fiscal start.

And for FY 2014, FY 2015 etc, you could use this formula:

```
=IF(MONTH(Created)>6,"FY "&YEAR(Created)+1,"FY "&YEAR(Created))
```

that formula returned 2015.

I tried using the formula `TEXT([DateField],”yy”)` and nesting it inside the `datefield` area. it returns `05` for (1905) instead of `15` for 2015

Is there a way to return in the `YY` format?

Comment: "it returns 05 for (1905) instead of 15 for 2015" can you be more clear on this?

Comment: After removing the FY text, the formula returned 1/2/1905 instead of the 1/2/2015 based off of the date field selected when viewing the column in a list.  When I nested the formula in this formula: TEXT([DateField],”yy”) it gave me the 2--digit year as requested but it was the year (05) instead of the expected year (15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(MONTH(Date)>6,"FY "&RIGHT(YEAR(Date)+1,2),"FY "&TEXT(Date,"yy"))
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I removed the "FY" and came to the 2-digit year i was looking for.  Thank You

Comment: Fiscal years start on Oct. 1. This formula says that any month that is after June belongs to the next fiscal year, which I believe is incorrect. Maybe some firms go off of June-to-June, but the government goes off of Oct. 1, so to accommodate that, it ought to be `=IF(MONTH([Created])>9,RIGHT(YEAR([Created])+1,2),TEXT([Created],"yy"))` - if the month is after Sept., it will take the year, add one, then take the last 2 characters. Otherwise, we just get the "yy" of the "Created" date field.

Answer (score 1):

Fiscal years start on Oct. 1, at least the government goes off of Oct. 1, so to accommodate that, it ought to be:

```
=IF(MONTH([Created])>9,RIGHT(YEAR([Created])+1,2),TEXT([Created],"yy"))
```

If the month is after September, it will take the year, add one, then take the last 2 characters. Otherwise, we just get the "yy" of the "Created" date field.

**Breakdown**

The statement takes the form: `IF(some condition,do this if met,else do this)`

`RIGHT(some field, n)` will grab as many `n` characters as you specify starting from the right, backwards, going to the front of the value. (Using `LEFT(some field, n)` grabs `n` characters starting on the left, going forwards.)

You can get any `mm-dd-yyyy` or `yy` value from a date using `TEXT(field,chars)`. Example:  Given a column "Publication Date", you could do this: `TEXT([Publication Date],"mm")` and get `07` if the date was `07-02-21`. You can also just do `MONTH([Publication Date])`, and that works for numeric comparisons, whereas using the `TEXT()` operator does not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone. I wanted to get the "FY2122" format. Based on the comments from everyone here, I used the following formula, which worked. Might be useful for others too.

```
=IF(MONTH([DateField])>6,"FY"&TEXT([DateField],"yy")&RIGHT(YEAR([DateField])+1,2),"FY"&RIGHT(YEAR([DateField])-1,2)&TEXT([DateField],"yy"))
```